# PostgreSQL - join multiple lines from one column into one string in SELECT query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to join all results from one column in `SELECT` query into one string.

Some of you might be familiar with `C#`:

```
string.Join(separator, stringArray)
```

The following statement doesn't return all results as one string

```
SELECT CONCAT(text) FROM orders
```

Does anyone have an idea of how to replicate that `C#` code by means of `SQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `string_agg()`:

```
select string_agg(text separator, ',')
from orders;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
Gave me the chance to google PostgreSQL equivalent - `string_agg(DISTINCT text, ', ')`. 
Works like a charm!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . Clearly, I was confused.